# Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.FINAL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependencies, pom.xml

**[>     I am having a spring MVC project where I want to integrate Hibernate, however when I am adding Hibernate dependencies to POM.xml

> file it showing error "Missing artifact
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.FINAL" and the jar
>   dependency is not getting resollved. Same thing is happening with the
>   jdbc14 jar
>
> ```
> I tried different versions of the jar but still the issue persists.][1]**
> ```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.raj</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring-MVC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>Spring-MVC</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.FINAL</hibernate.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servletapi.version>3.1.0</servletapi.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
        </dependency> -->


        <!-- Spring Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- embedded Jetty server, for testing -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
                <configuration>
                  <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                  <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/spring-mvc-form</contextPath>
                  </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- configure Eclipse workspace -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <wtpContextName>spring-mvc-form</wtpContextName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I expect the jars to be downloaded, please tell me if I am missing something.

[image: capture of pom.xml]

Answer (score 0):

change the following property ("FINAL" replace with "Final")

```
<hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Comment: There was some issue with the hibernate version and my eclipse. I upgraded the version in my pom.xml file and it worked